# Hyper directory - Can a (Linux) directory in addition to a list of subdirectories and files also contain text itself?

Tags: hyperlink, filesystems, webserver, wiki, directory-structure

Under Linux, are there ways to add comments, description (text, rich text, hypertext .. ) to a directory *itself*, rather than by means of auxiliary files *in* such a directory, like README.txt, INSTALL.txt, NOTE_ON_WHY_WE_DID_THIS_THIS_WAY.txt, .. ?

In such a generalized directory, a directory entry (subdirectory/file) would be represented as (hyper)link, at least in one view of such a generalized directory. A "classical directory view" may also be available for generalized directories, in which the commments, description, mentioned above, would be omitted, or be available through an auxiliary file. I am aware this may require either special formatting of the storage medium, or a software layer on top of a classical disk formatting structure. The views would have to be derived from the generalized directory and not vice versa (in order to avoid consistency problems between the views).

Answer (score 1):

Not in general, but some file-systems have [extended file attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes). You could use [getfattr(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getfattr.1.html), [setfattr(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfattr.1.html). See [attr(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/attr.5.html), [listxattr(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listxattr.2.html), [setxattr(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setxattr.2.html) etc...

<sup>AFAIK, few utilities are using these extended file attributes (and that surprises me; I would imagine that desktop environments would e.g. use them to store e.g. the MIME type of files, but they usually don't). There is a significant (file-system specific) limit on these extended attributes, e.g. 255 bytes</sup>

A more practical and traditional way would be to decide to store your additional meta-data in some hidden directory (with a name starting with a dot, like `.git/` used by [git](http://git-scm.com/))

Comment: The max. number of text bytes in extended file attributes in most cases appears to have to be too small for an intermediate size text. ( I was hoping that what I am looking for could simplify the implementation of websites, wiki servers .. )

Answer (score 0):

I can't refer to all filesystems, but at least in extX, directory contains only the names of files/dirs which are in this dir, their inode numbers, and offset beetween where the next pair (dir/file - inode) starts. Generally such data which describe dirs are kept in inode structure (not inside directory itself), for instance owner of dir, atime, ctime extended attributes, number of links and so on, all these things are there. You can look on such structure in kernel source, and there is not such field which allows to put "labels" on the file/dir. In theory you would use some "unused" fields of this structure, but only in theory since these is very limited space.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question, but I believe not. From what I remember, directories are just pointers to files other directories, so I don't think it would be possible to store text in them. Maybe if you re-enginner the whole filesystem...